# Running an accessibility application requires following steps

Tags: windows, microsoft-metro, elevated-privileges

I am trying to create a UI automation client for metro app automation but when i set the uiAccess to true it gives the message (while building),

> Microsoft Visual Studio
>
> Unable to start program 'C:\myprogram\myprogram.exe'.
>
> The application manifest has the uiAccess attribute set to 'true'.
>   Running an Accessibility application requires following the steps
>   described in Help.
>
> OK |  Help

And when i click on Help button it opens the browser page:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/query/dev10.query?appId=Dev10IDEF1&l=EN-US&k=k%28VS.DEBUG.ERROR.LAUNCH_ELEVATION_REQUIREMENTS%29&rd=true

But that page refers to common questions about Visual Studio 2013 (as of 2013-December-24).

Can anybody help and provide the former content of the page or some help how to resolve this problem with launching from Microsoft Visual Studio an application with `uiAccess` set to `true` in its manifest?

Comment: It's unfortunate that this was closed. It's a real UX fail on Microsoft's part. In my case, the solution was to change the VS2013 shortcut compatibility to "run as administrator" and relaunch VS. Note that this was after VS had already detected that it needed to be run as administrator and had relaunched itself accordingly - still no go. The compatibility checkbox HAD to be set.

Comment: this helped me a lot today! thank you for your "ambiguous, vague, incomplete, overly broad, or rhetorical and cannot be reasonably answered in its current form" question and comment.